# Magento Admin 404 after sessions expire

Tags: magento

We have just moved our joomla/magento site to a new server.  We are now getting some intermittant 404 errors for the magento admin panel

We are able to use the Magento Admin periodically. After a couple of hours we will start getting a 404 after logging in. Once we manually clear the magento cache it starts to work again.

When we start getting the 404 the issue appears to be related to the URL.

Our setup is:

1. Joomla is in the root directory.
2. Magento (1.5.0.1) is in a sub-directory /magento

When the Admin panel (www.oursite.com.au/magento/_admin) is working the url after login is

- https://www.oursite.com.au/magneto/index.php/_admin/..........

When the 404 starts occuring the url drops the 'magento' out of the url and becomes

- https://www.oursite.com.au/index.php/_admin/............

After manually cleaning the magneto cache the issue is resolved.  After a few hours it starts to occur again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution to the problem that we have been having.

Some where along the line the permissions of the magento/var/cache directory where incorrect.  Apparently if magento can't write to this directory it starts writing to the global /tmp directory.

This post on the magento forum has the info and solution:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/282544/#t391174

Hope it helps someone.